# Static common value function in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say we have Matrix4 class (matrix four by four).

User of this class often wants to initialize variable of Matrix4 type with identity matrix.

There are two choices I know:

1. Provide member function SetAsIdentity for that class that changes the value of *this. So user would do something like this :

   ```
   Mat4 m;
   m.SetAsIdentity();
   ```
2. Provide static member(or non-member) function that returns a static const identity matrix, something like this (see update) :

   ```
   static Mat4 Mat4::Identity()
   {
       static const Mat4 m{ 1, 0, 0, 0,   0, 1, 0, 0, 
                            0, 0, 1, 0,   0, 0, 0, 1 };
       return m;
   }
   ```

   and then use it like this:

   ```
   Mat4 m = Mat4::Identity();
   ```

In my opinion, I'd like to use 2 more than 1 just because it can be used in one line of code.
Is there a better way to initialize matrix but still using **defaulted default constructor** (the original reason is to make the class stays POD)? Could number 2 be implemented with constexpr? Speed difference, if any?

**UPDATE:**

Requirement:

- The default ctor is defaulted
- Must be able to define non-default ctor (2 doesn't actually conform to this. It compiles on msvc but not on gcc or clang).

One comment(by juanchopanza) suggests to use a dummy type :

```
class Mat4
{
public:
    struct SIdentity {};

    float f[16];

    Mat4() = default;

    Mat4(SIdentity) : f{ 1, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
    {}
};
```

and to initialize it:

```
Mat4 m(Mat4::SIdentity{});
```

which seems(?) to be more elegant (although it requires awkward instantiation, will the variable be optimized away?)

**UPDATE2:**

One comment(by geza) suggests making SIdentity ctor as constexpr ctor. This adds benefit of being able to do (static) constant initialization and compile time initialization/construction

Comment: note, in 2. you could just do `return {{ 1, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0, 0 }, 
                            { 0, 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 1 }};`

Comment: Why do you need it to be a POD?

Comment: I would provide a constructor that takes a dummy `Identity` type. Then initialize internally.

Comment: @M.M that's right. That's most definitely better than what i have at above.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Now that i think about it, I guess POD is not really required in this question. Originally, I was thinking of to avoid implementing the default constructor to initialize the values. I'll remove POD from the question

Comment: The 1st one seems better to me. You can simply call `SetAsIdentity()` from constructor as well to avoid extra line during initiation.

Comment: Another option would be to define a static member, `static const Matrix4 Matrix4::identity`, which is the identity matrix. This way you can write `Matrix4 m = Matrix4::identity`.

Comment: @M.M, I just checked it seems that if i want to do that, i can't define any other constructor other than ```Matrix4() = default```

Comment: ^tested in clang & gcc : https://godbolt.org/g/VYJHv5
although it seems to be compilable in msvc

Comment: ^although, i also can't define, in clang & gcc, other non-default ctor using (2) above.

Comment: @ManojKumarRai I guess this is what i meant by the original POD requirement in the question. I updated the question to restrict defining default ctor

Comment: @geza it can also be done that way, but then it could have static initialization order problem

Comment: @bysreg: I see. You could have defined a constexpr constructor for that, but you said that you can only have a default constr. What's the reason that you can't define other constructors?

Comment: @bysreg: btw, if your class doesn't have any constructors, then you can initialize its data members "manually", so Matrix4::identity wouldn't need dynamic initialization. Like `Matrix4::identity = { { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0... } };`

Comment: @geza what i meant is that i have to default the default ctor (the original intention is so that the class can stay POD). I would like to be able to define other non-default ctor (will update the question). I didn't know this before, but as you said, that aggregate initialization is only allowed if the class has no user-provided constructor(except explicit defaulted, or deleted ctor). clang & gcc follows this rule, but it seems that msvc doesn't

Comment: @bysreg: hmm. If you keep it POD, then it can be aggregate initialized, which will be performed compile time, so there won't be static initialization problem. I could ask the next question, why do you want to keep it POD?

Comment: @bysreg: use `constexpr Mat4(SIdentity)`, and it will surely be optimized away (and it can static initialized, too)

Comment: @geza i think you're right. that's definitely seems to be better (will update)

Comment: Uhm what? Why would you use a constructor taking a dummy type? Why not a named function `makeIdentity` or what not? What am I missing?

Comment: @NirFriedman That's the approach 1. It's just that it uses two lines and the values are initialized after construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is that there is no reason to use any of the techniques presented so far.

1. Do not use a mutating function called after construction. This is ugly as it is two lines instead of one, and worse you lose the opportunity to make the value const or constexpr.
2. Do not use a static local for a constructor that can be made constexpr. Edit: though there is no real performance hit in this case (as I erroneously wrote before), a function with a static local cannot be `constexpr`. So this is still a poor choice for constexpr constructible types. An alternative approach would be to use a constexpr static global.
3. There is no reason whatsoever to resort to something as hacky as feeding a tag type into the constructor.

I don't really understand the conflict with POD at all. And the simplest way to construct a class to a special value is simply to make a static function returning it by value (without using a static local). The following seems to meet all of your requirements.

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

struct MatrixFour {

    MatrixFour() = default;
    constexpr MatrixFour(const std::array<double, 16> x) : m_data(x) {}

    static constexpr MatrixFour makeIdentity() {
        return MatrixFour({1,0,0,0,
                           0,1,0,0,
                           0,0,1,0,
                           0,0,0,1});
    }

private:
    std::array<double, 16> m_data;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_pod<MatrixFour>::value, "");
    constexpr auto x = MatrixFour::makeIdentity();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no conflict at all with POD. POD is originally mentioned just to avoid suggestions where you assign the identity in the default ctor. Other suggests to use aggregate initializer on the static function, which i cannot use, because i'd like to define other ctor in addition to the defaulted default ctor. Your answer is the best answer so far to my question on how to make (2) faster and be constexpr.

Comment: 1. Agreed. 2. If the variable can be static initialized, there won't be guard variable, and there won't be any problems with thread safety. 3. I don't consider this a hack. The language doesn't give us tools to differentiate between constructors when the parameter list is the same. Tag type is a perfectly fine solution in this case. I don't consider standalone creator functions a perfect solution, it has its shortcomings.

Comment: @geza 2. You are right re guard variable etc. However at that point you may as well just make a constexpr static variable and not bother with a function at all. 3. Constructor tags are definitely a hack. They are used in the standard in certain places, because with ultra generic code (e.g. `std::pair`) you can't guarantee movability, so you can't use make functions. Otherwise, what is the downside of a make function? At the end of the day it's just a function returning stuff; that's a pretty big chunk of what real code looks like.

Comment: Though note, that having a static local precludes constexpr, so that's a pretty strong reason why it just doesn't make sense to use a static local when you have a `constexpr` constructor. Either use a static variable or a static function, not a static local. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: 2. I agree with you, I just wanted to point out the guard variable can be avoided. 3. I see your point, and mostly agree with you. However, not every class have move constructors. And compilers may copy construct the returned value, which can be expensive. And yes, there is a rare occasion, where a class is not movable. Constructor tags doesn't have any drawbacks I know, they are just considered ugly, hackish.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care that your `Matrix` would be initialized as identity matrix by default, you could simply write something like this (simplified data structure). Here, every `MatrixPOD` will at first be an identity matrix until you change the value to something else or add other constructors that overwrite the initial value of `x`:

```
struct MatrixPOD {
public:
    int x[4] = { 0,0,0,1 };
    MatrixPOD() { };
};

MatrixPOD gi;  // identity matrix, even at file scope
```

If you can live with a plain data structure, you could also provide a macro for initialisation, e.g:

```
struct MatrixPOD2 {
public:
    int x[4];
#define IDENTITY { 0,0,0,1 }
};

MatrixPOD2 gi2 = IDENTITY;
```

However, if you want to have a class with more constructors, and if you want to have a "pre-initialization" only when stated explicitly, then you could introduce a global identity-instance that you use then for initialising other matrix objects. See the following code, where a private constructor is used to initialize this global identity-instance:

```
struct Matrix {
public:
    int x[4];
    Matrix() = default;

    const static Matrix identity;

private:
    Matrix(bool identity) {
        if (identity)
            memcpy (x,x_identity,sizeof(x));
    };

    const static int x_identity[4];
};

const Matrix Matrix::identity(true);
const int Matrix::x_identity[4] = { 0,0,0,1 };


int main() {

    MatrixPOD p;  // always an identity matrix
    Matrix m; // not an identity matrix
    Matrix mi = Matrix::identity;  // identity matrix since explicitly assigned

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this have a possibility of static initialization order issue? some static variable in other translation unit that initializes with ```static const Matrix m = Matrix::identity``` could have been initialized first before Matrix::identity is initialized.